# Animated dashed line in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

I'm new with cytoscape.js and I'd like to know if it's doable to animate a dashed line like in Cytoscape software (Marquee equal line type for example). The aim is to represents a movement.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to see a feature like this, feel free to make a pull request on the `unstable` branch for a numeric `line-style-offset` style property (offsetting the dots or dashes of the line style by the specified value).  That's sufficient to enable the feature, as you can use numeric style properties with the existing animation APIs.

Comment: Ok I will do that. I just wanted to be sure it doesn't exists at the moment before asking for it.